# Spring kafka batch listener prints whole consumer record

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Config

```
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, 10);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 50*1024*1024);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
```

prints the whole payload, any help in getting of it and consumer the data would be helpful 
ConsumerRecord(topic = xxxxxxx, partition = 2, offset = 1512343, CreateTime = 1591460009853, serialized key size = 8, serialized value size = 9506789.......

Log size is too big to print and analyze

Edit 2: could see more this exception in that big log
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Interrupted while queuing ack

Comment: `>prints the whole payload` - it's not clear what you mean, or what software is "printing" it. If it's your code, you can modify what's printed. Spring only logs the whole record in DEBUG logs. We could add an option to prevent that, if that's what you mean. Exactly "where" is it being "printed"?

Comment: this is an error log, something went wrong, assuming this could be of message size

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the log (minus the record) so I can see exactly which logger(s) need to be updated?

Comment: Thanks Russell, still i am hitting a rock, why these occurred in first place,love the message not to be printed just metadata is good enough for any audit/bug

Comment: The fix should be released Wednesday. That error is because you are calling `Acknowledgment.acknowledge()` on a `foreign` thread with MANUAL_IMMEDIATE AckMode; and that foreign thread has been interrupted, preventing the queueing of the ack.

Comment: Making max_poll_record =1 (making it non batch) helped only reducing this error, increased the time outs but just did little help.  Option of truncating logs would help here as we cannot avoid GC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opened a [new feature request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1499).

> could see more this exception in that big log Caused by: `org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Interrupted while queuing ack`

That error is because you are calling `Acknowledgment.acknowledge()` on a foreign thread with `MANUAL_IMMEDIATE AckMode`; and that foreign thread has been interrupted, preventing the queueing of the ack.

It's best to call it on the listener thread, if possible.

Comment: To my bad luck,  ack in on same thread and same function, i am trying my option to modify session, heartbeat, poll interval to see if it all fine incase of GC pause  (which is my suspect) given the exception

Comment: Also tying auto commit to see if that helps

Comment: Feature request should help with option of printing only metadata, few events of large message(snappy compressed in my case) size can be helped. To avoid this error, we might have to work on GC pauses. when service/processor turns good, partition reassignment help it get it processed